How to Convert a xml file to FormUrlEncoded key value pair string data as below by any library or RestSharp client?
I have a xml data as below
<Data>
    <collection_method>send_invoice</collection_method>
    <customer>cus_PyyS4EerCT1e4G</customer>
    <payment_settings>
        <payment_method_options>
            <acss_debit>
                <mandate_options>
                    <transaction_type>abcd</transaction_type>
                </mandate_options>
            </acss_debit>
        </payment_method_options>
        <payment_method_types>1</payment_method_types>
        <payment_method_types>2</payment_method_types>
    </payment_settings>
    <custom_fields>
        <name>UDf1</name>
        <value>abcd</value>
    </custom_fields>
    <custom_fields>
        <name>UDf2</name>
        <value>efgh</value>
    </custom_fields>
    <account_tax_ids>1001</account_tax_ids>
    <discounts>
        <coupon>1001</coupon>
        <discount>100</discount>
    </discounts>
</Data>

and i want to post a the above data as a body Content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded  for that i need below structure string key value pair data  from above xml
collection_method=send_invoice&Data.customer=cus_PyyS4EerCT1e4G&payment_settings[payment_method_options][acss_debit][mandate_options][transaction_type]=abcd&payment_settings[payment_method_types][0]=1&payment_settings[payment_method_types][1]=2&custom_fields[0][name]=UDf1&custom_fields[0][value]=abcd&custom_fields[1][name]=UDf2&custom_fields[2][value]=efgh&account_tax_ids[0]=1001&discounts[0][coupon]=1001&discounts[0][discount]=100
please give me suggestion how to do that easily using .net
Thanks
Surajit Kundu
i am trying to convert a xml data  into key value pair string for UrlFormEncoded body data type and  i need a suggestion how to do that
